# unity playerpref lifetime score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been struggling getting my head round to adding a total lifetime score to my scoremanager.

I want total score be accumulative even when the player dies

I have tried introducing playerprefs, however this keeps on resetting to 0 on start.

My script which currently works and saves the highscore using playerprefs;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;


public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{


public Text hiScoreText;
public Text totalScoreText;


public Text distanceText;
public Text scoreText;
public Text hiScoreText2;
public Text totalScoreText2;

public GameObject NewHighScorePanel;

public float scoreCount;
public float hiScoreCount;



public float pointsPerSecond;
public bool scoreIncreasing;
public bool shouldDouble;


public Transform Player;
public Transform checkpoint;

public float distance;
public float score;
public float totalScore;
private float pointsToAdd;




// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    this.Player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
    this.checkpoint = GameObject.FindWithTag("LevelStart").transform;

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
    {
        hiScoreCount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Awake()
{
    score = 0;
    totalScore = 0;
}

void Update()
{


    distance = 10 * (Player.transform.position.x - checkpoint.transform.position.x);

    totalScore = distance + score;

    /* if (scoreIncreasing)
     {
         scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * distance;  //was Time.deltaTime


     }*/

    if (totalScore > hiScoreCount)
    {
        NewHighScorePanel.SetActive(true);
        //Debug.Log("new highscore is achieved!");
        hiScoreCount = totalScore;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", hiScoreCount);

    }

    //InGame Scoring


           totalScoreText2.text = "" + Mathf.Round(totalScore);
    hiScoreText2.text = "" + Mathf.Round(hiScoreCount);


    //GameOver Score
    distanceText.text = "Distance: " + Mathf.Round (distance);
    scoreText.text = "Treasures: " + Mathf.Round(score);
     totalScoreText.text = "Total Score: " + Mathf.Round(totalScore);
    hiScoreText.text = "High Score: " + Mathf.Round(hiScoreCount);


}


public void AddScore(float pointsToAdd)
{

    score += pointsToAdd;
}
}
```

on start
currentLifetimeScore

on Update:
effectively totalscore = distance + score + lifetimescore;

Comment: `totalscore = distance + score + lifetimescore`? Are you sure you didn't mean `lifetimescore = distance + score + lifetimescore`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `PlayerPrefs.SetXXX` functions, the data is not saved right away on the disk but stored in the memory. Once `OnApplicationQuit` is invoked in Unity, all changes you to the PlayerPrefs are now saved. This is likely the issue. Explicitly call the `PlayerPrefs.Save` function after calling the `PlayerPrefs.SetXXX` function to save the changes.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", hiScoreCount);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

---

Unrelated but due the unnecessary rounding code in your script, I believe that your score variables should be `int` instead of `float` then use `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` to save the `int`. Please ignore this if you have a good reason to make them `float`.